# Fast argmax in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I have a array (v) in numpy of shape (m, 1). I have another 2d array (A) of shape (m, n). Now I want to add v to every column of A and then compute the argmax of every column. I use broadcasting for the addition part and then use `np.argmax`. But I have to repeat this operation many times and m is also in the range of 10,000s. Do you have any suggestion to speed up this computation?

```
v = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
A = np.array([[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]])

# Add v to every column of A
B = A + v

# Compute argmax of every column of B
argmax_cols = np.argmax(B, axis=0)
```

A numba approach which I tried which led to a 30% speedup. I was wondering if I could do better -

```
@njit((nb.int64[:])(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:,:]), parallel=True)
def find_index_numba(v, A):
    
    _, n = A.shape

    indices = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int64)

    for j in prange(n):
        summation = np.add(v, A[:,j])
        indices[j] = np.argmax(summation)

    return indices
```

EDIT:

Can there be some other optimizations if A is the same everytime and only v changes whenever I call this function?

Comment: How do you have to repeat this?

Comment: and what led to the conclusion that your current approach does not satisfy in speed?

Comment: I have wrapped this in a function which is called multiple times. On profiling, this step takes around 0.05 seconds every time it is called. So I was wondering if it could be sped up further.

Comment: are there any upper or lower limits? Lets say if a value of v is bigger than THRESH than it will be the argmax regardless of the (far smaller?) values of A? So in some cases it would be enough to argmax a vector instead of a matrix? Just an idea

Comment: Do you want an example of multiprocessing for your case?

Comment: @Klops I have tried parallelizing within numba but not with multiprocessing. Do you think they might lead to different speedups? Also, your previous idea is interesting but both A and v usually have values in the same range.

Comment: `multiprocessing` will probably be a costly aside. I have barely used `numba` but `parallel=True` - what does that mean? It doesn't specify a number of threads in itself. or, does it come with a tiny default? Other things: do you need to release the GIL anywhere? Maybe you need a Cython/Rust extension? I'm just spitballing; you've already typed your `numba` decorator so I guess you probably know most of this

Comment: @roganjosh njitted function cannot operate on CPython objects so the GIL is not a problem. Numba behave like the GIL has been release. In fact, Numba threads are not visible by the interpreter (typically OpenMP threads). THe number of threads should be the maximum concurrency the processor supports, so the number of hardware threads / core. Numba use LLVM-Lite internally which uses LLVM. The overhead of Numba is pretty small (for array, it is just some wraparound checks). AFAIK, the default Rust compiler is based on LLVM so I expect about the same performance.

Comment: @roganjosh For Cython, It uses the GNU stack by default on most platforms (AFAIK LLVM can also be used). GNU GCC is sometimes better to vectorize loops but this is dependent of the target code so one need to test. Anyway, I think the backend compilers certainly matters more than the use of Numba here, although it might be some ways to help the backend compiler so to produce a better code (if even possible) whatever the language/tool.

Comment: Why not use a Numpy array of the C order(row-major order) and ```argmax(..., axis=1)``` on it? It's much faster than the Fortran ordered case.

Answer (score 1):

I have something that **might** be faster. This code is more cache-friendly, but can't use multiprocessing. On single CPU it is 50-300% faster.

Cases for it to be faster:

- n and m are small (<100)
- you use multiprocessing on some higher level

```
@nb.jit((nb.int64[:])(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:, :]), parallel=True)
def find_index_numba3(v, A):
    m, n = A.shape

    n_chunks = 4
    chunk_size = n // n_chunks + 1
    maxima = A[0, :] + v[0]
    indices = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int64)
    for i_chunk in nb.prange(n_chunks):
        chunk_start = i_chunk * chunk_size
        chunk_end = min(chunk_start + chunk_size, n)
        for j in range(1, m):
            for i in range(chunk_start, chunk_end):
                current_value = A[j, i] + v[j]
                if current_value > maxima[i]:
                    indices[i] = j
                    maxima[i] = current_value

    return indices
```

Applied @Jérôme suggestion below.

```
@nb.jit((nb.int64[:])(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:, :]), parallel=True)
def find_index_numba3(v, A):
    m, n = A.shape

    n_chunks = 4  # hardcoded, for better cpu you might want to set higher
    chunk_size = n // n_chunks
    maxima = A[0, :] + v[0]
    indices = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int64)
    for i_chunk in nb.prange(n_chunks):
        chunk_start = i_chunk * chunk_size
        chunk_end = max(chunk_start + chunk_size, n)
        for j in range(1, m):
            for i in range(chunk_start, chunk_end):
                current_value = A[j, i] + v[j]
                if current_value > maxima[i]:
                    indices[i] = j
                    maxima[i] = current_value

    return indices
```

And it gives significantly better results (test for m=5000, n=10000):
[image]

Comment: Good! This code can be parallelized by splitting the `i` loop. The idea is to compute `i` by chunks and the chunks can be computed in parallel in an encompassing loop (so there is 3 loops: i1 iterating on i chunks, j iterating on rows and i2 iterating on the content of the current chunk). This is only efficient if `n` is large enough though. Otherwise, false-sharing effects will cause performance issues. If `m>>n`, then a parallel reduction can be done : this function can be applied on each `A[0:chunkSize, :]` slice in parallel, so then the result of the slices can be merged.

Comment: @JérômeRichard great idea! I applied it and it indeed gives better results. It is usually 10-20% faster than OP function, but significantly faster for n=1000+

Answer (score 0):

This is another idea you might not have thought about yet. It might have some overhead, but this comes at the benefit of nice progress bar and an incredibly easy implementation. Install pandarallel by running `pip install pandarallel`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandarallel import pandarallel

pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)

v = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
A = np.array([[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]])

# Add v to every column of A
B = A + v

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(B)

# using apply without pandarallel
df.apply(lambda x: x.argmax())

# using apply with pandarallel
df.parallel_apply(lambda x: x.argmax())
```

See project website for more information https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/

The website notes:

> Parallelization has a cost (instantiating new processes, sending data via shared memory, ...), so parallelization is efficient only if the amount of computation to parallelize is high enough. For very little amount of data, using parallelization is not always worth it.

Comment: The code of the OP is already parallel and the OP did not ask for a "nice progress bar and an incredibly easy implementation" but to "speed up this computation". I doubt this solution is significantly faster, or at least there is no evidence of that.